# Micro SDHC class 10 + adapter

Tags: speed, sd-card, adapter, sdhc

I have bought a micro sdhc 32gb class 10 but my camera only accept std sd card, so i would like to know if the adapter will keep the same speed of the card, or there is some kind of class too.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The adapter will always be lossy (electrical connection), but shouldn't be noticeable, assuming some basic level of quality in the adapter.

Obviously, a poorly-made adapter with a bad connection isn't going to work very well.

Answer (score 0):

Adapter is only a bunch of wires. Any will do.